# What are the advantage of using a generics-where-clause call over a non-generic call?

Tags: c#, generics

I've seen some examples where they transformed a call like

```
void Add(IDrawing item);
```

into

```
void Add<TDrawing>(TDrawing item) where TDrawing : IDrawing;
```

Beside tricking the intellisense into displaying the name of your class instead of the interface name when calling the function, because of inferred type usage in C#4, are there any other advantage to using the second approach?

To answer Jon Skeet, the code our programmer used is:

```
public ObservableCollection<IDrawing> Items { get; private set; }

public void Add<TDrawing>(TDrawing item) where TDrawing : IDrawing
{
   this.Items.Add(item);
}
```

I don't see any advantage here for using a generic instead of just using a parameter of the `IDrawing` type. I presume there must be some case where its very appropriate. I was curious to see if I was missing something.

Comment: "Beside tricking the intellisense into displaying the name of your class"...damn, I didn't realize it would do that, that's almost reason enough for me to want to use the second approach.

Comment: Minor side note: the .NET term is "generics"; they are quite different than C++ or T4 "templates".

Comment: Updated to use generics. Sorry about that, olds habit are olds.

Comment: It's not exactly "tricking" intellisense. In the second example, the type variable TDrawing is strongly typed as an IDrawing. Useful in code as well as in intellisense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on what's going on elsewhere in the implementation. Here's a different example:

```
void Add<TDrawing>(TDrawing item, IList<TDrawing> list)
    where TDrawing : IDrawing
{
    if (item.SomePropertyOfIDrawing)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Now you wouldn't want to take an `IList<IDrawing>` here - because then you couldn't use it if you had a `List<Painting>` for example... whereas with the generic version above, it's absolutely fine for `TDrawing` to be `Painting`: the constraint ensures that property is available for the `if` condition, and the fact that it's generic allows you to safely add the item to the list.

If you have *full* examples where you don't think there's a benefit, it would be worth presenting those specifically.

EDIT: No, in the exact example now given there's no advantage in making it a generic method.

Comment: Indeed. Much more useful at the level of a generic class, so that the whole class has type knowledge based on the generic constraints.

Comment: That's adding something to the original example though (the need to keep both parameters of the same type)...the analog to the original example wouldn't be just changing to list to IList<IDrawing> but also TDrawing item to IDrawing item.  I mean, its interesting and all but doesn't really answer what he's asking.

Comment: @kekekela: Originally there wasn't nearly enough context - now there's a fuller example, it's easier to answer.

Comment: Maybe the programmer was in a generic mood and was writing everything in a generic way. Though, I like the fact that the intellisense now display the class name instead of the interface name. Upon digging a little in some possible alternative, I think that it could be useful when creating a function that require two interface in an object: like `void Add<TDrawing>(TDrawing item) where TDrawing : IDrawingItem, ISomethingElse`

Answer (score 1):

Think of this scenario:

```
void Add<TDrawing>(TDrawing item, Func<TDrawing, bool> func)
{
   //implementation
}
```

Now when calling this method, at compile time, you'll be able to access the specific proeprties of the specific `TDrawing` being passed into this method to use with the `Func`.

```
Add<MyDrawing>(drawing, m => m.SomeMyDrawingProp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of the version with the "where" clause can be very different from those without when a struct is passed as a parameter.  Storage locations (including parameters) of interface types hold heap object references.  Type-coercing a struct which implements an interface to a storage location of that interface type will create a new heap object with the same fields and methods as the struct, copy all field contents (public and private) to that new object, and then store a reference to that object in the storage location.  By contrast, copying a struct to another storage location of that struct type will copy all the fields (public and private) but leave the result as a struct, rather than a heap object.